# Как сделать группировку с выборкой по времени с определенным интервалом?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Есть DataFrame, у которого есть столбец "Дата звонка".
Для того чтобы вывести сумму звонков за каждый час, я делал вот так:

```
per = df_4380['Дата звонка'].dt.to_period("H")
df_new = df_4380.groupby([per,'Кто ответил', 'День недели']).sum().reset_index()
```

Сейчас мне нужно вывести сумму звонков за каждые 30 минут, а не за час.

Как это сделать?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь [pd.Grouper()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
res = df_4380.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Дата звонка', freq='30T'),'Кто ответил', 'День недели']).sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: Да, работает! Спасибо.